# API call failed after working hundreds of times ... any thoughts?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I've hit a glitch with an API call. It worked faultlessly hundreds of times and then failed. The code is simply checking the progress of a processing job. If progress is not 100 then wait and try again.

This is what the code looks like

```
generating = 1

ep_check_state = 'https://api.sproutvideo.com/v1/videos/{}'.format(sv_video_id) # the details of the last video uploaded

while generating:
    r = requests.get(ep_check_state, headers=json_headers)
    r_json = r.json()

    progress = int(r_json['progress'])
    state = r_json['state']

    if progress < 100:
        print('Final video is still processing... progress={} ... sleeping'.format(progress))
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print('Final video progress: {} state: {}'.format(progress, state))
        generating = 0
```

And this is the error that it tripped after polling successfully 1934 times!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sv_uploader3.0.py", line 465, in <module>
    r_json = r.json()
  File "/Users/administrator/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any thoughts on why this may have happened? And how I can catch this in the future so that it doesn't crash the process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you control the API? If you don't, then the API is probably down or overloaded.

Comment: Do you have the raw contents of what you're getting in? Perhaps the JSON Decoding isn't working because it isn't JSON? Maybe there's something in the file that the base decoder doesn't know how to process, and you need to write a custom decoder? Tough to answer without know what the value of "r" is in this case.

Comment: Also, now that I look over your question, you are getting a JSON decode error. This specific error means that there is no beginning to the JSON (the response is an empty string). So you must have sent a request which didn't send back any data.

Comment: you probably got rate limited by the api as you hit it too many times, therefore the response does not contain the expected json

Comment: @DevLounge, if he did, then wouldn't there be an error 429?

Comment: it depends if the api sends proper error codes when they rate limit

Comment: Before you do `r_json = r.json()`, log `r.text` so that you know what the API is actually returning. It could be returning an HTML page.

Comment: Also, instead of doing `while generating:` and setting `generating` to `False`, you can do `while True:` and then use a `break` statement to exit the loop.